# OpenShift v3 MySQL Permission errors on image pull

Tags: mysql, openshift

I pulled backups from OpenShift v2 for our MySQL DBs, and followed the procedure in this [article](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/migrating_applications/database_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-database-applications-mysql) on porting over to OpenShift v3 Pro plan.

After getting the DB up and running, I believed I accomplished the final step noted:

```
Grant all privileges on <dbname> to <your_v2_username>@localhost, then flush privileges.
```

By doing the following in mysql terminal:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbName.* TO 'userNameInMySQLSecret'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And even tried this just to make sure we were all good:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'userNameInMySQLSecret'@'%';
```

The userNameInMySQLSecret is the same one used in the OpenShift v2 DB.

The DB has been up and running for 22 days, but today I got a notice on a stuck deployment.  Apparently for some reason the MySQL DB is trying to pull a new image (does this mean I have lost all of the data stored in DB ?) and in the logs I see this error:

```
---> 15:44:23     MySQL started successfully
---> 15:44:23     Setting passwords ...
2018-01-31T15:44:23.388611Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I thought the permissions above would have solved this issue, but apparently I am still missing something.  I had this setup running on OpenShift v2 for almost a year with no problems, so I am sure I have missed something on the configuration in the new v3 platform.

Is it possible to get this pod back up and running without losing all of the data since the port from v2?

How do I prevent this permissions problem from popping back up?

Why would the MySQL DB tried to pull a new image in the first place?

Comment: As a Pro customer, have you tried reaching out to [Red Hat support](https://access.redhat.com/support)?

Comment: The main link on the support page would not allow me to create a case, but I found an "open case" link on a secondary support page, and have opened a case.  I have not received a response yet, if they are able to solve the issue I will update with their solution.